# Why appengine application is constantly calling datastore_v3.Put

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I implement a Java application which is constantly calling datastore_v3.Put. 
I log each time I record any record in the database (it's two places in the code) and I have no logs. 
Yet from the RPC stats I get

```
RPC Stats
RPC Count   Cost    Cost %

 memcache.Get   59409   0   0.0%

 **datastore_v3.Put**   19  0   0.0%

/favicon.ico    9   0   0.0%

/   7   0   0.0%

POST /addkvartal    3   0   0.0%

 memcache.Set   19  0   0.0%

 datastore_v3.RunQuery  9   0   0.0%
```

Why it's shown and why favicon.ico is calling it. 
I hope my question is clear and I can provide further information if needed.

Comment: "19" calls does not seem that much. Are you using persistent sessions? They might hit the datastore.

Comment: favicon.ico is downloaded by browsers to find an icon to use for the tab and bookmark bar.

Comment: I use persistent sessions so it may be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Thilo correctly pointed out, persistent sessions are backed by Memcache and the Datastore. Each time a new session is started, you will see one call to Memcache and one call to the Datastore.